# Can I extend maximum zoom level in google map for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am using google map to implement floor image over Map for that I use below code

```
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 23.04, longitude: 72.53, zoom: 11.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    view = mapView

    let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.040254, longitude: 72.532212)


let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 23.039054, longitude:72.530254)

   let overlayBounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: southWest, coordinate: northEast)

    let icon = UIImage(named: "IMG-01")

    let overlay = GMSGroundOverlay(bounds: overlayBounds, icon: icon)
    overlay.bearing = 0
    overlay.map = mapView
```

Here I can zoom map max at 21. But i want more zoom special for overlay image. I tried below function also for extra zoom but not get success

```
mapView.setMinZoom(11, maxZoom: 25)
```

So is there any way to extend maximum zoom level?

Comment: You cannot extend but you can still scale your view.

Comment: @ChanOnly123 Can you please suggest how to scale the view

Comment: view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.0, y: 2.0)